# WCF REST web service on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, iis

I have written my first REST web service in VS 2010 using .NET 4.0 and works fine on my machine.

Now I try and put it on my web server which has IIS 7.5 but I get 403.14 error. My application pool is Integrated 4.0. What all should I check to get this working? The confusing bit is that all forums talk about web.config but I have .config file.

On my machine is url is

```
http://localhost/Parking.Service/evals
```

(which works). Now on the webserver the dll is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RestService - should the url be (on the webserver) be

```
http://localhost/RestService/Parking.Service/evals
```

Please help.

Comment: 403.14 - Directory listing denied status code. Can you browse the default website from IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a .svc file with WebServiceHostFactory configured like this

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="MyService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" Language="C#" debug="true" %>
```

See this article for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx
[on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) from MSDN Magazine.

Comment: My service is in .NET version 4.0. As suggested I put the svc file, but then I got error 500. I then registered asp net (by aspnet_regiis -ir) which bought me back to error 404.0. According to the link I have enabled 'WCF' feature which installed .NET version 3.0 and 3.5. aspnet_regiis does not work on version 3.0 or 3.5 - should it? I am still getting 404.0. What could be wrong?

Comment: Change the Process Model Identity of your ApplicationPool to NetworkService in IIS.